# sumproduct as string

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

i want to evaluate the below formula:

```
SUMPRODUCT(--(etf_data!$CG$7:$CG$19500="Listed"),
           --(etf_data!$C$7:$C$19500=Template_region_listed),
           --(etf_data!$CM$7:$CM$19500="Equity"),
           --(etf_data!$BW$7:$BW$19500="fiat"),
           etf_data!$BP$7:$BP$19500,
           etf_data!$OH$7:$OH$19500)
```

but everytime i try to add a criteria it gives me #Value! error. probably it is because of the 255 limit. is there any way to split the formula in 2 and evaluate them separately? any other solution?

Comment: if you think the formula is too long and needs to be abbreviate, you could used defined names to define each of your ranges.  Choose a short name and it will save you some characters

Comment: instead of converting criteria with -- and using , to separate your ranges, you can save 2 characters bu replacing the , with * and drop the --.  Any boolean result or number as a string will be converted to a number when sent through a math operation.

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. how can i put the named ranges instead of the ranges?

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. how can i put the named ranges instead of the cell ranges? For example the named range "MarketStatus" = INDIRECT(Sheet2!$A$1) where A1 =  $CG$7:$CG$19500. How can i put marketstatus instead of $CG$7:$CG$19500?

Comment: I get no errors adding another criteria, can you post what you tried?

Comment: A defined name can be created in several ways.  The simple method is to select/highlight your desired range and then in the top left corner where it usually lists the active cell, type in a name.  Alternatively you can go to the Formula ribbon, and use the "Defined Names" section and click on define name and manually enter the range or add a formula if it suits your purposes.

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT(Defined_Name_1*Defined_Name_2*Defined_Name_3)` is a way you could go.  Just need to make sure the length of each defined name range is equal.

Comment: i get an error when i add more than 5 criterias.